# Where is the screen rotate lock in Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: display, gnome-shell, screen, 22.10

Where is the screen rotation lock in Ubuntu 22.10 ?

(This prevents the display from rotating, if you rotate your laptop screen by 90°, 180°, or 270°).

I expected this to be available in the quick settings popup, but it is not there.
I searched in the Settings app, and did not find it there.

(I thought this feature existed in prior versions of Ubuntu).